# What is the optimal way to modify data (pixel values) only for a small part of a large GeoTIFF?

Tags: geotiff-tiff, cloud-optimized-geotiff

I have a large GeoTIFF files (blocksize=512, compression=deflate), where I need to modify/update only a small part of data (small region). What is the optimal way to do it (using GDAL, GeoPython libraries, or anything else)?

Optimal should mean that data modification is done in the place (in a short processing time); without the need of re-writing or re-saving the complete big GeoTIFF file (which takes a long time processing).

This capability is possible e.g. in NetCDF format with python netcdf4 library. Is there some alternative for GeoTIFF? (Maybe no, but also answer "No" helps :-).

Comment: It may be difficult to find a totally optimal solution for compressed GeoTIFFs. If new data does not fit into the disk space that was used for old, better compressible data, then some re-writing must happen. One easy method is to use gdalwarp for warping new data into already existing target image https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html#cmdoption-gdalwarp-arg-dstfile.